# Password reminder with md5-encrypted passwords

Tags: php, sql, encryption, passwords, md5

I'm creating the "Forgot your password?" page for my website.

Obviously, when a new user creates an account, the php script encrypts the password choosen using the md5 algorithm.

Now, everything works fine, except that when the user requests a password reminder using the "Forgot your password page", the email that he recive returns the password encrypted in md5, and not the real one.

The following is the code I'm using.

```
$query2="SELECT password FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
$risultato2 = mysql_query($query2) or die ($query2);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($risultato2))
{
     $passToSend = md5($row['password']);
}

echo "<center>We have sent an e-mail to <b>".$email."</b> containing a link to recover your     password.</center>";

$mittente = 'From: "My website" <mywebsite@service.com> '; 
$destinatario = $email;  
$oggetto = "Recover your password"; 
$messaggio = "The password you've choosen during the sign up process is: ".$passToSend."\n\nIf    you'd like to change your password, please visit    http://www.mywebsite.com/mydashboard/changepwd.php\n\n Please ignore this message if you haven't requested a password reminder.";                 
mail($destinatario, $oggetto, $messaggio, $mittente);
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never try to provide a feature to allow people to recover their password. If you are storing passwords correctly, then that should be impossible.

Note: You should be hashing passwords before you put them into the database, not when you take them out and MD5 is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) so you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Generate a token made up of random characters (make it quite long). Store it in a table next to their user id (or the primary key of your users table) and a time stamp. Email the user that token (embed it inside a URL for their convenience). When they follow the link, give them a form which allows them to set a new password for their account (which you can identify from the token).

Delete the token after they reset their password, it should be a one time use token.

Delete tokens that are unused after *some time period* (e.g. 24 hours) with a cron job.

Comment: Better would be to store only a **hash** of the token, otherwise an attacker with read access to the db (SQL-injection) can request a reset, read the token and has access to the account.

Comment: Or have the token "expire." In other words, normally leave that column in the database empty and only fill it with a randomly generated token when the user requests a password reset. Then the column should be cleared again either after the reset or after a few hours, whichever comes first.

Comment: Thank you all, I will follow your instructions, you have all been very clear and useful. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelGoldstein - That's actually what Quentin wrote, "Delete tokens that are unused...". It is not even necessary to delete the timestamped tokens, just check if the token is still valid when the user clicks the link.

Comment: Ah @martinstoeckli that makes a lot of sense. More sense than what I suggested.